# Unable to add resize functionality in android widget

Tags: android, resize, widget

I have made an analog clock widget. The widget is working perfectly fine except that I am unable to add the resize functionality. Based on tutorials and other references `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"` code does the job, but its not working.

I have also added `<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"`
I have kept minSDK to 14.
Widget image size is 390x390pixels.
I have kept elements only in "drawable" folder.

Am I missing anything? Please let me know if any more information is required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.
Add this code to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Anyway better is to see your codes. codes that you used it for your clock xml.

go this link and take a look at codes:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915277/android-widget-size-issue-on-orientation-change)